# Why doesn't my List object contain a definition for 'Add'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently trying to get a dataset from SQL server into a list so I can then display this on a page. I've honestly looked at a lot of answers here, and every different attempt brings me to a different error.

From what I've read, this *should* work. `ScriptList` is a `List` and should have the `Add` functionality. However, it simply doesn't. This is my code at the moment:

```
    public ScriptList Index()
    {
        var scriptList = new ScriptList();

        //List<ScriptItem> scriptlst = new List<ScriptItem>();

        string connectionString = _configuration["ConnectionString:localhost"];

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string statement = "SELECT ScriptGUID, ScriptName, ScriptDescription, DateAdded FROM dbo.Scropts;";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement, connection);
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    scriptList.Add<ScriptItem>(new ScriptItem{GUID = Convert.ToString(reader["ScriptGUID"]),
                                                              Name = Convert.ToString(reader["ScriptName"]),
                                                              ShortDescription = Convert.ToString(reader["ScriptDescription"]),
                                                              DateAdded = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateAdded"])});

                }
            }


        }

        return scriptList;
    }

}
public class ScriptList
{
    public List<ScriptItem> ScriptItems {get;set;}
}
public class ScriptItem
{
    public string GUID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ShortDescription {get;set;}
    public DateTime DateAdded {get;set;}
}
```

This gives me the error below:

> 'ScriptList' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and the best extension method overload 'ConfigurationExtensions.Add(IConfigurationBuilder, Action)' requires a receiver of type 'IConfigurationBuilder'

I've tried change the definition of `ScriptList` to `List<ScriptItem> scriptlist = new List<ScriptItem>();` however, this then results in the error below:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'asp.Pages.ScriptList'

I really don't understand what's wrong here. Why does `scriptList` not have the `Add` functionality, and why is it that `scriptlist` ***does*** yet despite that both are declared as `List<ScriptItem>` that aren't (apparently) the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you have created a class that has a `List<T>` *member*. That doesn't mean that your class inherits all members from said member.

You're simply looking for `scriptList.ScriptItems.Add()`, note the added `ScriptItems`. *That* is your list, not your `ScriptList` class.

Answer (score 4):

You would want to use `scriptlist.ScriptItems.Add()` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Your list is defined within the ScriptList class, so you need to do:

```
scriptList.ScriptItems.Add();
```